# updatedb doesn't include all attached drives

Tags: command-line, locate, updatedb

Manpage states the by default updatedb includes the entire file system. I have two usb attached drives that don't get included updatedb. I can create my own db file for each drive but wondering if I can force updatedb to include them?

I realized this was so when locate didn't find files I new existed on one of the attached drives. Executing sudo updatedb had no effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look in `/etc/updatedb.conf`, particularly the `PRUNEPATHS` parameter which lists paths to be excluded from the database.

Answer (score 2):

The PRUNE list of exclusions in the updatedb.conf was the problem, it eliminated anything from /media where I had attached my USB HDDs.  I removed the entry from the PRUNE list and now updatedb works as I want it to work.

Comment: Accept an answer, rather than editing the title to be "SOLVED".  It may take two days, but you still should not edit the title to say "SOLVED" and instead accept an answer.

Comment: OK, I accepted the answer that helped and understand the reasoning for doing that but why is it a problem adding solved in the posting's heading?  Is it because of a delay in it showing up?

Comment: Because this is not a forum site - and adding 'solved' is NOT the way to mark the issue as 'solved' here on Ask Ubuntu or StackExchange sites.